# If $A^2 = O$, is $A = O$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I think the answer is "no", but I'm trying to find the flaw in this reasoning:

$A^2 = O \implies AA = O \implies A^{-1}AA = A^{-1}O \implies A = O$

This shouldn't be true, as far as I know, so what did I do that I'm not allowed to do?

Comment: You assume that $A$ is invertible...

Comment: Counterexample: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What you obtained is a contradiction with the assumption that $A^{-1}$ exists since $A=0$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as indicated by comments is that $A$ is not necessarily invertible. $A^{-1}$ does not necessarily exist. So from $AA = O$ you cannot simply multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: In fact no nilpotent matrix is invertible, since $A^n=0$ implies $\det A= 0$ and hence $A$ is noninvertible.

Answer (score 1):

After AA = 0,
You divided the 2 sides by a zero value, which is not allowed.

Something like -
2x + 1 = 0
Dividing both sides by (2x +1),
1 = 0

Comment: If division by zero were the only problem, there'd be no ral problem with it: Either $A=0$ and we are done; or $A\ne 0$ and $A^2=0$ implies $A=A^{-1}A^2=A^{-1}0=0$ as intended. However, even if $A\ne0$, it may not be invertible if the domain is not e.g. the real numbers (cf. AlexR's comment and Timbuc's counterexample)

Comment: More than an answer this should be a comment, imo.

Comment: Ah I see, yes, sorry. Cannot comment as I have only 24 reputation right now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Donkey_2009, the question is: how can he comment on the OP post when he has no sufficient reputation? This is a bad idea, imo.

Comment: @Timbuc see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12228/should-we-really-have-a-reputation-requirement-for-commenting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/how-to-make-a-remark-when-reputation-is-under-50 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16560/answers-of-the-form-i-dont-have-enough-reputation-to-comment-but

Comment: As it happens, there is a way for a user with 1 reputation to make a comment on any post: write a very short answer containing a link to another post; the system will convert it into a comment, which you can then edit.

Comment: @Donkey_2009, I'vbe been around for a while and I had no idea about that. Too long, cumbersome and messy, imo. If, after all, newbies can comment, why not allow them from the beginning?! Another problem is that the site seems to be completely closed, or almost, to new ideas and insights to enhance it. Anyway, thank you for the links.